# Converting CMSampleBuffer to Data and Data To UIImage does not work, why

Tags: ios, swift4

Just to test we try to convert CMSampleBuffer from capture output to Data using Swift 4 with following function.

After we get data we converted this frame data to UIImage and it returned nil. We could not get UIImage.

We are making this test because we are going to send the data to an other device to get image eventually.

But we are unable to get an image at the same device from data yet.

Are we missing something.

PS:We reduced the FPS to 1 for this test.

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                   didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                   from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

   func frameData() -> (Data) {

        let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!)
        let src_buff = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!)

        let data = Data(bytes: src_buff!, count: bytesPerRow * height)


        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))


            return (data)

    }

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
         let data = frameData()
         guard let image = UIImage(data) else {return}
         self.myImageView.image = image
     }



 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a way it is sort of crude though.

I created data with

```
  let data = testImage.pngData() as Data?
```

and streamed this data and converted it to UIImage with

```
  let image = UIImage(data:Data)
```

But to do it I converted CMSampleBuffer to UIImage first.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation of `UIImage` constructor with data. I am pretty sure you can not construct it simply with raw pixel data which seems like you are doing. This constructor probably expects png or jpeg data. The reverse of something like `pngData()` method on instance of `UIImage`. To construct image from raw data you can use a bit lower API. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256403/526828) looks promising but you will need to port it to Swift from objective C or find similar solutions.

You will see that there are multiple parameters needed next to just raw data like width, height and pixel format. Image data are not as simple as that. So to reconstruct it you will also need to append this data. And since you want to send it to another device this might not be as easy.

Maybe to begin with it would be best to convert this into JSON. Simply use a base 64 encoded string to convert to/from string and data:

```
let dataInstance = Data(base64Encoded: stringInstance)
let stringInstance = dataInstance.base64EncodedString()
```

So now you can construct a dictionary like:

```
let imageJSONDescriptor: [String: Any] = [
    "width": imageWidth,
    "height": imageHeight,
    "rawRGBAData": stringInstance
]
```

Then create JSON data

```
let JSONData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: imageJSONDescriptor, options: .prettyPrinted
```

On the other side once you receive JSON data you need to convert it back to dictionary

```
imageJSONDescriptor = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .allowFragments)) as! [String: Any]
```

And get the values

```
let imageWidth = imageJSONDescriptor["width"] as! Int
let imageHeight = imageJSONDescriptor["height"] as! Int
stringInstance = imageJSONDescriptor["rawRGBAData"] as! String
```

I hope this fixes your issue but the thing is you may actually need more data than just width and height.

Comment: In documentation it says UIImage(data:Data) could return image or nil. Returns nil if it could not initialize image with supplied data. So we should able to get image info in Data somehow. Hence we have problem with data creation?

Comment: Also I can convert image to String data and send it to an other device as JSON and convert String data to UIImage at that remote device. At the moment I am trying to stream.

Comment: @Hope Yes well the data you are using does not provide image info. Image info is part of the sample buffer but the data you created only contains raw pixel data which is not enough to reconstruct an image. Ergo you get nil. As I see you have already figured out you can use some standard formats which include both (pixel data and metadata) such as png or jpeg. So there is no problem with data creation, you are simply missing information that is needed to reconstruct your image.